# Remove Admin/System Accounts from People Search

Tags: search, user-profile-service, people-search

We have several SharePoint only accounts that don't correspond to any users in our Active Directory. How can I exclude these accounts from People search?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you were looking for a way to remove the accounts from the search results?  If so, you can create a crawl rule to remove them from the results.  You can create a managed property for the account name and exclude it from the results.

See this thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ar/sharepoint2010general/thread/7a9dc9ea-85ea-4092-89c7-1c6440bb06ad

Answer (score 1):

In the User Profile Service Application, change the permissions on who can use the profile features (Manage User Permissions).  Instead of the all users groups, change it to a group that includes only the users who should be using the profile features and such.  Then re-run your search crawls.

Answer (score 1):

You can also exclude the non-people accounts by creating the import connection so it only pulls from an OU with people. (Provided AD is set up with People in one OU and Service Accounts in a seperate OU.) If not you can add bitwise filters to eliminate the extra profiles.