# peopleresult page - hide users if displayname is blank or has certain word

Tags: 2010, search-results, people-search

Is there a way hide results (people's record) that does not have a name in the display name or display name has certain words from the peopleresult page?

Comment: Is this SP 2013?

Comment: SP 2010. Sorry forgot to add that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a copy of the Current People Results scope and configure a new scope to hide the people that meet your rules.

Information about managing search scopes is available [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792872(v=office.14).aspx)

I found [this site](http://tutorial.programming4.us/windows_server/sharepoint-2010---configuring-search-settings-and-the-user-interface---search-scopes.aspx) and [this site](http://zieglers.wordpress.com/2010/08/03/creating-shared-custom-search-scopes-in-sharepoint/) that seem to explain quite a bit about the customization of Search Scopes

Comment: Looks like search scope wont work because I want to exclude results where preferredname contains "admin-" and exclusion rule in scope does not give you contains or not like. it only gives you equal "="

Comment: Ah =[ Maybe you can create a profile property called Exclude From Search and exclude users with that set as True ?

Answer (score 0):

You can create extra property in the SharePoint User Profile not in AD, that used to identify the accounts which needs to exclude from People search.you can create a crawl rule to remove them from the results

[How to exclude Admin Acounts from People Search Result](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/64434/how-to-exclude-admin-acounts-from-people-search-result)

[Remove Admin/System Accounts from People Search](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/35241/remove-admin-system-accounts-from-people-search)